# Layout template in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

So this is my first post. I guess, this is the right place for me to learn some new things in ASP.net. Well, I just started creating a system using Asp, and just to ask ask anyone here, how to apply the downloaded layout template into my master page? Looking forward to any feedbacks. Have a nice day!

Comment: First, Welcome to SO. Second, your question is too vague. You need to provide the relevant piece of code/markup that you are having problems with. For instance, post the Master Page markup and the template you downloaded here...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question does not fit the standard required for this site, best if you [read the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)... even better reading is this set of [FAQ's from the meta part of the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Once you've read them, come back with your question

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a layout in to your ASP.NET website is a matter of breaking it up in parts like header, footer, main content etc. The header and footer parts are good candidates to go into your master page, but the main content will be different per page, so that belongs into the pages itself.

Here you have a good read about site wide layouts using masterpages:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs